# sending a javaobject from my C#

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps-api-3

Good day

I want to send a object to my Javascript  from my C# program I am using a webBrowser object to show my website on my forms app.And I need help sending the object from C#.

Here is my working code in javascript:

```
map.addMarker({ 
id: 1,
lat: -26.9200682,
lng: 28.5713688,
icon: "icons/red.png"
event: {
name: 'click',
callback: function() {
    window.external.Test('Marker 1')
  }
 } 
});
```

Here is what i think my javascript should look like if i want to to get a  object:

```
map.addMarker({
var obj:window.external.setMarker()
```

}
   );

Here is the function that will execute if the object is made correctly.
    
      `addMarker: function(opts) {
      var marker;
       opts.position = {
          lat: opts.lat,
          lng: opts.lng
         }
        marker = this._createMarker(opts);
        if (opts.event) {
          this._on({
            obj: marker,
            event: opts.event.name,
            callback: opts.event.callback
            });
          }
      },`

and here is the C# code that is called:

```
 public  class marker
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }

        public marker()
        {
           id = 3 ;
           lat = -28.9200682 ;
           lng = 29.8713688;
           icon = "icons/red.png";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need have access to C# objects from js code you can serialize your C# object. You can use Microsoft serializer for that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So I have to convert...Serialize my object in C# before I send it back to my JavaScript?       
  public object setMarker() { 
            marker markera = new marker();

            var javaObj = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            var ja = javaObj.ConvertToType(javaObj, somthing   );

            return ja;



        }
What willl the return type be?

Comment: As I understand you need write some content (portion of JS code) in webBrowser. I don't have expirience how working with this object. I hope you can find way for this. So if you serialize your c# object you receive string (JSON format) that can be use in JS code. Like this:
var obj= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(options) // where options it is your C3 object with neccessary options